# get the html of each p element, store in an array, except the ones that contain an img with jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been playing with the each(function() to try to get every "p" element to be stored into an array. I also tried to use .get().

Basically I currently have this very basic code :

```
var text = $(source).children('p').html();
```

I know this only gets the first paragraph element from the "source" parent. Im wondering how I can retrieve only the p elements which do not contain an "img", and then store each one into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find elements without an `<img>` tag, you can use the selector `"p:not(:has(img))"`

To map elements to their contents, you can write

```
$(source).children("p:not(:has(img))").map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
}).get();
```

Comment: what's the `.get()` on the end doing?

Comment: @Alnitak: It creates a normal array from a jQuery object.

Comment: but (AFAIK) the map shouldn't be returning a jQuery object

Comment: ah, I was looking at the _other_ `map` function

Answer (score 0):

you want to use the :has selector:

```
$('p:not(:has(img))')
```

see my fiddle!
http://jsfiddle.net/uFFgz/

edit: updated my fiddle to put them in an array:
http://jsfiddle.net/uFFgz/1/